# What is the behavior of procedure declaration without parameter type?

Tags: function, delphi

While trying some code, I found that if we provide a parameter to a function or procedure without type, it will not give us a compile-time error.

Why is this happening and please give some explanation as I am not able to find such a code anywhere?

procedure declaration:

```
Procedure TestProc(var objTest);
```

If we remove the keyword `var`, then compile time error is presented as `Type required`.

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: It's an [untyped parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Untyped_Parameters).

Comment: It's largely syntactic sugar that is equivalent to passing a pointer. The extra functionality is const untyped parameters which can't be emulated using pointers.

Answer (score 7):

[Untyped parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Untyped_Parameters) are usually used when the actual type of the parameter is irrelevant. One example would be the standard "[FillChar](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.FillChar)" procedure that fills a variable - ANY variable - with a specified byte value. Instead of needing several (actually an infinite number of) overloaded procedures to be able to fill an arbitrary variable with a value, an untyped parameter is used.

An untyped parameter (like any other parameter) can be "input" (data going INTO the procedure/function) by using the `CONST` prefix, "output" (data coming OUT of the the procedure/function) using the `OUT` prefix, or both (data being sent into the procedure, modified, and sent back out) by using the `VAR` prefix.

As you may notice, the FillChar procedure uses a `VAR` prefix, although an `OUT` would be more correct. However, the FillChar procedure was "created" at a time, when `OUT` prefixes didn't exist in the language (only `CONST` and `VAR` existed, and of the two, `VAR` was the only one that allowed data to be going back out of the procedure, so `VAR` was used).

Answer (score -2):

Like Victoria said it is a [untyped parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Untyped_Parameters)

If you would like to create a procedure or a function that can handle different types of parameter, you should use [overload](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)). Everytime you call a overloaded function it depends on your Inpout what exclusive function oder procedure would be used.

Comment: There are cases for untyped parameters. Like FillChar, Move, etc. Try writing those functions using typed parameters with overloads.